# PuTTy interruption triggers the remote server to disable the network for 10-20 minutes

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, tmux

In the last days I had a problem. Randomly when I was connected to my remote Linux Server **or** when I was connecting for the first time to the server I got the message  ***Network error: Software caused connection abort.***.

I read different solutions and none worked for me. It's weird that in the last 2 months I didn't had this problems with this server from Hetzner.

So every time when this problem happens the PuTTy window freezes. I close the window and I have to try 2-3 times to connect to the server to be able to reconnect again.

What is also confusing is that I use TMUX. And for example if I have something downloading in a TMUX session the network connection is broken for 10-20 minutes.

If I CTRL+C and close the existing process and try to download again it stays like this:

[image]

**Is this a firewall problem? Why the network doesn't work and the process from tmux freezes?**

My Firewall from Hetzner dashbord (should I delete these?)

[image]

[image]

Full overview:
[image]

Comment: It sounds like a firewall issue, such as from a numerical packet/connection rule that limits the amount of connections to a specific port; however, usually when such a rule is enforced, once the limit is reached, the connection is disconnected server side. Is port `22` exposed to WAN? If so, it's generally a bad idea to expose default encrypted traffic ports like `22`, `1194`, etc. to WAN as you'll normally get thousands of blocked attempts from port scanners _(I always recommend setting a high DNAT port north of `40000` since port scanners won't scan all 65,535 ports)_

Comment: But if SSH breaks and crashes why the network connection is broken also for the server.

because I have 4-5 TMUX sessions opened and when the error occurred then the network connection also fails and my wget processes fails too and for 20-30 minutes I cant restart my downloads in those TMUX opened sessions.